# Separate Fraction accordingly using javascript

Tags: javascript

I can I separate fractions accordingly as numerator and denominator using javascript split.

```
var str="1/2+2/4";    
str.split('/').split('+');//not Working
```

Now I want it like `num=[1,2]` and  `den=[2,4]`

Comment: Please see the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help) for posting questions.

Comment: _I want it like num=[1,2] and  den=[2,4]_ That grouping doesn't make sense. If you're parsing an expression, you don't want a list of all your numerators and another list of all your denominators. That doesn't help get you to a useful place where you can evaluate the expression. You more likely want to create a tree for the expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to split an array.

*An alternative is splitting the string by symbol `+` and then execute the function `reduce`.*

```js
var str="1/2+2/4+3/4";
var result = str.split('+').reduce((a, c) => {
  var [num, den] = c.split("/");
  a.den.push(den);
  a.num.push(num);
  
  return a;
}, {num: [], den: []});

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: But this is not generic right !  What if my input is 1/2+2/4+3/4+... ?